# Trouble with http request from Google Compute Engine

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu-14.04, google-compute-engine, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to set up a Google Compute Engine server to pull options data using  Python [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/remote_data.html). When I make this request from my Mac at home, I only have problems late at night when Yahoo! is resetting its servers (the data is being pulled from Yahoo! Finance). But when I try doing the same thing from my Compute Engine server, the request always fails for some of the stocks I'm interested in, although it typically works for options on larger companies, such as 'aapl' or 'ge'. On my computer at home, running it at the same time, the same requests succeed for both small and large companies.

The requests do typically take a few seconds, maybe as many as 15. Is there a way to get to more extensive logs as to what is going on when I make these requests on the Google servers? The only things I can think of would be that there are permissions issues for some reason with these specific http requests or that there is a timeout configured that's interfering. But as far as I can tell, the general timeout should be 75 seconds for that kind of request, and there's no way it's taking that long.

Here's a sample of what I see from the python shell:

```
>>> from pandas.io.data import Options
>>> spwr = Options('spwr', 'yahoo')
>>> data = spwr.get_all_data()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/disk1/venv/optbot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/data.py", line 1090, in get_all_data
    return self._get_data_in_date_range(dates=expiry_dates, call=call, put=put)
  File "/mnt/disk1/venv/optbot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/data.py", line 1104, in _get_data_in_date_range
    frame = self._get_option_data(expiry=expiry_date, name=name)
  File "/mnt/disk1/venv/optbot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/data.py", line 723, in _get_option_data
    frames = self._get_option_frames_from_yahoo(expiry)
  File "/mnt/disk1/venv/optbot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/data.py", line 655, in _get_option_frames_from_yahoo
    option_frames = self._option_frames_from_url(url)
  File "/mnt/disk1/venv/optbot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/data.py", line 692, in _option_frames_from_url
    raise RemoteDataError('Received no data from Yahoo at url: %s' % url)
pandas.io.data.RemoteDataError: Received no data from Yahoo at url: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=SPWR&date=1430438400
>>> aapl = Options('aapl', 'yahoo')
>>> data = aapl.get_all_data()
>>>
```

I've never yet been successful in getting the options data for 'spwr', but usually it will work for larger companies.

Any ideas how I might fix the issue? Or get to logs that will tell me more about what's happening here?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that this is an Ubuntu issue. Trying it on an Ubuntu box at home, I get the same behavior as I am on Google Compute Engine, whereas it works on my Mac and works for 'aapl' or 'ge' on Ubuntu. Just not sure why Ubuntu would be rejecting the smaller companies? Maybe higher latencies on the Yahoo end? Maybe Yahoo routes it differently in some relevant way?

Comment: I figured it out. It's an issue with Pandas 0.15.2. I noticed that I was running 0.15.1 on my Mac, where it was working, and when I reverted to that version on the Ubuntu machine, it started working. I'll file the issue with Pandas so they'll know.

Comment: Please, update your question accordingly and set your own answer as a valid answer. This helps ranting the questions better by making it more acurate and useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by an issue in Pandas 0.15.2. When I reverted back to Pandas 0.15.1, it started working again. The [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/22) has been filed with Pandas. Check there to see if it has been resolved in later releases.